# How to use Multiple DataContexts(DbContext) in a Repository .Net Web API

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core

I am developing a web API in .NET Core with multiple DataContexts(DbContext). I have used repository pattern to handle DB calls. The Repository class accepts a DbContext as a generic type.

```
public class Repository<T> : IRepository where T : DbContext
{
      public Repository(T context) : base(context)
      {
      }
}
```

This Repository class injects to service classes as IRepository from the Startup. I want to connect with 2 databases. So I`m using 2 DataContext classes and passed them in to repository class in the startup.

Here is my Startup class,

```
services.AddTransient<DataContext1>(x => new DataContext1(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database1")));
services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository<DataContext1>>();
            
services.AddTransient<DataContext2>(x => new DataContext2(Configuration.GetConnectionString("Database2")));
services.AddTransient<IRepository, Repository<DataContext2>>();
```

When I request IRepository it always injects the Repository class with the last DataContext(DataContext2). What is the best way to solve this problem without affecting to the API performance(Memory / CPU).

Here is my Service class,

```
private readonly IRepository _repository;

public BookService(IRepository repository)
{
    _repository = repository;
}
```

Comment: 2 implementations mapped to one interface, well so at runtime you must have some mechanism to **select** the implementation you want. It could be some metadata, associated name (exposed via some property) ... By going that way, the injected type should be `IEnumerable<IRepository>` and from that you can filter for the repo you want. A custom DI container may provide some other solutions to deal with this scenario, e.g: `autofac` provides `Named & Keyed services` https://autofaccn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/advanced/keyed-services.html You can use an attribute to select your dependency

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you should at least create one repository interface for each type of database in order of the dependency injection system can handle it.

Answer (score 0):

Inject a factory class for the repositories instead of an instance of the repositories themselves.  Implement the factory methods to suit your needs.